# Need help in solving matrix involving linear equations

Tags: matrices

Find the sum of all real numbers $a$ which make the following system of
linear equations $$ \begin{pmatrix} 5 & a \\ a & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x+5y \\ 6x+y\end{pmatrix}$$

have solutions except $x+0,y+0$

I solved up to: $$ 5x+ay=x+5y$$ $$ax+3y=6x+y$$

I have now this system of two linear equations. how I can continue?

Comment: simplify. you should get $x=(y \cdot (5-a))/4$ and plug this in the other equation

Comment: Maybe it is: except $x=0, y=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHS can be written to 
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 \\ 6 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$, therefore $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & a-5 \\ a-6 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=0$. It has non trivial solution iff the determinant is not equal to $0$. Solving this we get $a\neq 2$ and $a\neq 9$.

Comment: So the answer is 11 ?

Comment: Surely the determinant needs to be equal to 0 in this case as otherwise the only solution is x = 0, y = 0?

Comment: how you got a is not equa to 2 and 9? I am not being able to grasp

Comment: The determiant of the matrix is $12-(a-5)(a-6)$. Let it be zero, then there are two roots $2$ and $9$.